# Analysis of same deployed contracts in the network

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to analyze how many the exactly the same Solidity contracts were deployed into the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think etherscan provides a similar ability :

check https://etherscan.io/find-similiar-contracts

you could find similar contract to the deployed one with different levels of similarities.

Answer (score 0):

You can query contracts bytecode in the public dataset BigQuery https://medium.com/@medvedev1088/more-blockchain-analysis-on-bigquery-92a863137f01